Bicep role assignment
Im trying to do a role assignment usig BICEP. My goal is to assign the Databricks Access connector as the storage blob data contributor on Storage account.
Im deploying both, Databricks (with managed RG which contains my access connector) and storage account too.
I have the below code to do so: main.bicep
module databricks 'platform/modules/databricks/deploy.bicep' = {
  name: 'DeployDatabricksWorkspace'
  params: {
    workspaceName: workspaceName
    pricingTier: pricingTier
    location: location
    disablePublicIp: disablePublicIp
    vnetID: vNetId
    environment: environment
  }
  dependsOn: [
    virtualNetwrok
  ]
}

module accessConnectorStorageRbac 'platform/modules/roles/accessConnector/deploy.bicep' = {
  name: 'AccessConnector-rbac'
  params: {
    storageAccountName: storageAccountName
    principalId: accessConnectorPrincipalId
    roleId: 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe' // Storage Blob Data Contributor
  }
  dependsOn: [
    storageAccountModule
    databricks
  ]
}

and then I have the module where the actual deployment happens:
param disablePublicIp bool
param workspaceName string
param pricingTier string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param vnetID string
param environment string

var managedResourceGroupName = 'rg-mgd-databricks-${workspaceName}-${uniqueString(workspaceName, resourceGroup().id)}'

resource workspace 'Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces@2024-05-01' = {
  name: workspaceName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: pricingTier
  }
  properties: {
    managedResourceGroupId: managedResourceGroup.id
    parameters: {
      customVirtualNetworkId: {
        value: vnetID
      }
      customPublicSubnetName: {
        value: 'snet-ads-public-${environment}-weu-01'
      }
      customPrivateSubnetName: {
        value: 'snet-ads-private-${environment}-weu-01'
      }
      enableNoPublicIp: {
        value: disablePublicIp
      }
    }
  }
}

resource managedResourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: managedResourceGroupName
}

resource accessConnector 'Microsoft.Databricks/accessConnectors@2024-05-01' existing = {
  name:'unity-catalog-access-connector'
  scope:resourceGroup(managedResourceGroupName)
  dependsOn: [
    managedResourceGroup
  ]
}

output accessConnectorPrincipalId string = accessConnector.identity.principalId

Error Im getting is below:

Resource group
'rg-mgd-databricks-ads-mdp-comm-dev-weu-01-ntm7hk4xxjyda' could not be
found

so the rg-mgd-databricks-ads-mdp-comm-dev-weu-01-ntm7hk4xxjyda is the name where my access connector is. Not sure why I get this error since I have the dependencies.

Cross check your resource resource group name once?

@Bhavani what do you mean? My RG name is correct when I compare the one generted by the error and the deployed one

can you check the below answer, and let me know any concerns are there.

you shouldn't be deploying the connector in the managed RG cause it is managed by the azure platform. Ff you remove the scope / dependsOn on the accessConnector that should work fine.

If you would like to deploy the accessConnector resource in the managed resource group, it has to be done in a different module because the scope of the module deployment is different from the scope of the accessConnector resource (scope:resourceGroup(managedResourceGroupName))

@Thomas im not deploying it.it comes automatically since 2024 Jan.

Ho sorry didnt realized it was an existing resource for accessConnectors

I've just created a new data brick with your template and it did not create an access connector. any specific param i should be setting up ?

@Thomas thats strange. This is the case since this year. it deploys managed storage account and accessConnector.  You dont have to passs any specific parameter. I have the exact same code what I posted

Ok, ill retry later today.


Resource group 'rg-mgd-databricks-ads-mdp-comm-dev-weu-01-ntm7hk4xxjyda' could not be found

You have provided managed resource group of databricks workspace as
rg-mgd-databricks-${workspaceName}-${uniqueString(workspaceName, resourceGroup().id)}

But it is not the correct format of managed resource group. According to this

For Azure Databricks: By default, a managed resource group is created for you when your workspace is created. It will be named as  databricks-rg-<WorspaceName>-<RandomNumber>.

The managed resource group is not modifiable. you will be able to find the resource group and managed resource group in the overview page of data bricks as shown below:

Use that name as managed resource group name. Along with that instead of referring the name directly try to refer the managed rg property of workspace in a separate file this will be helpful to fetch the correct managed rg name as per the requiremnt:
param managedResourceGroupId string
 
resource accessConnector 'Microsoft.Databricks/accessConnectors@2024-05-01' = {
  name: accessConnectorName
  location: location
  scope: resourceGroup(managedResourceGroupId)
  properties: {
    // Specify any required properties here if necessary.
  }
}

